# Why my tracing of TCL execution does not stop at compile functions?

Tags: tcl

I have the following script, `~/tmp/2.tcl`:

```
proc p1 {a} {
    if {[expr $a + 10] > 100} {
        puts hi
    }
}

set a [p1 200]
```

I have a debug-build TCL v8.6.1, I like to trace what is going on inside TCL execution when I issue "`./tclsh8.6 ~/tmp/2.tcl`", so I use `gdb` to trace the the execution (inside gdb, `set args ~/tmp.2.tcl`,)

What puzzled me are:

```
1. In `TclEvalEx`(), it is command by command parsing and execution, I do not see any
script/command compiling.

2. I set breakpoints at `TclAttemptCompileProc(), TclCompileObj()` and `TclCompileExpr`(), 
they are not triggered.
```

What do I miss here? Why isn't there any script compiling?

Here is the backtrace of running TclEvalEx:

```
#0  TclEvalEx (interp=0x613680, script=0x674950 "proc p1 {a} {\n    if {[expr $a + 10] > 100} {\n        puts hi\n    }\n}\n\nset a [p1 200]\n\n", numBytes=87, flags=0, line=1, clNextOuter=0x0, 
    outerScript=0x674950 "proc p1 {a} {\n    if {[expr $a + 10] > 100} {\n        puts hi\n    }\n}\n\nset a [p1 200]\n\n") at ~/tcl8.6.1/source/generic/tclBasic.c:4935
#1  0x00007ffff7af0812 in Tcl_FSEvalFileEx (interp=0x613680, pathPtr=0x65beb0, encodingName=0x0) at ~/tcl8.6.1/source/generic/tclIOUtil.c:1809
#2  0x00007ffff7afb88f in Tcl_MainEx (argc=-1, argv=0x7fffffffde08, appInitProc=0x400963 <Tcl_AppInit>, interp=0x613680) at ~/tcl8.6.1/source/generic/tclMain.c:417
#3  0x000000000040095c in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffddf8) at ~/tcl8.6.1/source/unix/tclAppInit.c:84
```

**[UPDATE]** I am not sure what was going wrong, now the breakpoints do get triggered.

Comment: parenthetically, the first argument to `if` (and `while` and the 2nd arg to `for`) is already evaluated as an `expr`ession, so `if {$a + 10 > 100} ...` is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has quite a few internal entry points — it's not *in any way* a public API, and is subject to alteration without anyone announcing it — and `TclSetByteCodeFromAny` and `TclCompileScript` appear to be among the ones that you've missed. There are others too; it's actually awkward to list them all. You probably instead ought to set a breakpoint on `TclInitCompileEnv` which is the standard internal function used to set up the structure used by the compiler; anything *that calls it* is going to be of interest to you.

---

FWIW, the call to `proc` doesn't compile the body of the procedure. That's postponed until the code is needed, i.e., until the procedure is called. The call to `TclEvalEx` that you were seeing won't do much meaningful compilation directly.
Also, the non-recursive execution engine used in Tcl 8.6.* makes it *much* harder to debug with a tool like gdb. The C stack does not reflect the Tcl stack at all.

Good luck.

Comment: I am intrigued at your saying,  the non-recursive execution engine used in Tcl 8.6.* makes it much harder to debug with a tool like gdb, can you elaborate on this point?

Comment: It *used to be* the case that each procedure call would end up putting a few stack frames on the C stack, and so would some Tcl commands. Go back to before Tcl 8 and there was a direct correspondence, and a debugger could see exactly what Tcl was up to; that changed a bit with the bytecode compiler, but you could still figure it out fairly well. The NRE engine in 8.6 blows that away; you've usually no relation at all between the C stack and the Tcl stack now. We did have someone looking at how to improve the debuggability, but he died of cancer.